# Is my CPU really incompatible with Genymotion?

Tags: cpu, genymotion

On starting any Genymotion device, I get the error:

> Unable to start the virtual device. VirtualBox cannot start the virtual device. Your CPU is incompatible with virtualization technologies. For more information, check the log files. Please refer to: [www.genymotion.com/faq/logs](http://www.genymotion.com/faq/logs)

My CPU is the AMD Ryzen 3 2200G 3.5 GHz Quad-Core Processor, which includes a built in graphics chip (I think that's what it's called). I think my question is, is my CPU really incompatible with Genymotion? I have used VirtualBox before, so I know I can run a virtual machine. Is there any way to get around this error, or is my CPU really incompatible with this? If there is any questions on anything that would help, please ask, because I would really like to get Genymotion working.

Comment: Have you checked the log files for more information?

Comment: `I have used VirtualBox before` - can you use it right now? Do you have Hyper-V enabled in the Windows settings? What's its [startup mode](https://blog.zeddba.com/2017/09/25/disabling-microsofts-hyper-v-to-use-oracles-virtualbox/)?

Comment: @GuyIncognito: Yes I have, but I did not really understand most of it at all. Is there any way to send the file through here?

Comment: @GSerg: I am running Ubuntu, so I am not sure what you meant by the last two questions. As for the first part, Yes I can. I have run Windows 10 x32 through it, which seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to run Genymotion from a VM? If so, it will not work. Genymotion needs to be run from a real OS, not a VM.
Otherwise, see [Genymotion FAQ](https://support.genymotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002737597--Your-CPU-is-incompatible-with-virtualization-technologies-error)